# Where to find questions tagged [support] and [discussion]

Tags: support, tags, user-interface, meta, required-tags

Just wondering where questions with the `[support]` and `[discussion]` tags are filed... bugs and reqs are more obvious (there are tabs at the top), but I don't know where these other two can be found, other than by clicking on the tags themselves. Is that the only way?

Comment: Check the circular file, that's where most support posts end up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is the only way to see a list of questions tagged support or discussion.

Or, follow these links!

[Questions Tagged **`[Support]`**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support)
[Questions Tagged **`[Discussion]`**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion)

The reason for this, is because the usual bug tracking softwares will give users easy access to bugs or feature requests.  This is meant to mimic that functionality.

Comment: You can also enter `[Support]` or `[Discussion]` in the search box on the upper right. To see posts tagged with both simply enter  `[Support] [Discussion]`  [into the search box](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support+discussion).